# How to declare / change Java variables via gradle script

Tags: java, gradle

Is it possible to declare or change Java variables accessible via code with gradle?

I found [Is it possible to declare a variable in Gradle usable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java) and it tells me how to declare variables accessible via Java code for Android projects.

Is it possible to do the same with "normal" Java projects? I want to set a variable depending on which task is executed.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A common solution is to generate/detokenize a resource file (e.g. properties file) and read that from the Java code.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I already thought about that but I don't find a solution for this :( Do you have a reference to a code snippet or a snippet itself? Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001741/ch01.html#_keyword_expansion Instead of declaring a new `Copy` task, you'd configure the Java plugin's `processResources` task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @PeterNiederwieser I solved my problem:

In my gradle.build I use:

```
task usernameMaxio(type: Copy) {
  from 'src/main/resources/properties'
  into 'build/resources/main/properties'
  expand([
    username: 'Maxio'
  ])
}
```

and I access it via:

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream("properties/app.properties");
try {
    properties.load(stream);
} catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
    WebOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Couldn't read app.properties", "Fehler",
                                    WebOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
name = properties.getProperty("username");
```

And in my app.properties:

```
username=${username}
```