# How to use resValue?

Tags: android, gradle

I need to calculate integer value in build.gradle and then use it in my Java code. I try:

build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        resValue "int", "MY_VAR_NAME", "123"
    }
}
```

preprocess.xml in values directory:

```
<integer name="my_int_value">MY_VAR_NAME</integer>
```

And I get an error `Cannot resolve symbol MY_VAR_NAME`.

How to use it? Is there manual?

Comment: Here's a simple example to answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java

Answer (score 6):

### For Integer You Have to Use Like

`resValue "integer", "MY_VALUE", "123"`

### Or

**Define your Values in `gradle.properties` file , Like this  !**

```
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
# Your Values
MY_VALUE="123"
MY_VALUE1="124"
MY_VALUE2="125"

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
#http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

**Access from Your App  `build.gradle` file** 
`resValue "integer", "my_value", (project.findProperty("MY_VALUE") ?: "0")`
`resValue "integer", "my_value1", (project.findProperty("MY_VALUE1") ?: "0")`
`resValue "integer", "my_value2", (project.findProperty("MY_VALUE2") ?: "0")`