# Easily build same application with custom settings Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

I have an app that needs to be built with custom packages and a custom configuration file. I took a look on the internet and found about gradle `flavors`, but I couldn't figure out how to use them.

Basically I have an app with package `com.example.apps.myapp`. I need to build the same application using a different package `com.example.apps.myapp2` and a custom config class like `com.example.config.myapp2.Configuration`

I currently have this on my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.apps.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':api')
    compile project(':view-pager-indicator')
    compile project(':MaterialEditText')
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
    compile 'com.mauriciogiordano:easydb:0.1.0'
}
```

How easy is to create a gradle task or something to make those changes and build the application? PS: I have zero knowledge about gradle.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to declare flavours in build.gradle.
Just from official docs [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide). 
And for different conguration include `buildConfigField`. This fields you can read from **BuildConfig.FieldName** in any part of your code.

```
productFlavors {
            flavor1 {
                applicationId "com.example.apps.myapp"
                buildConfigField "int", "CONFIG_INT", "123"
                buildConfigField "String", "CONFIG_STRING", "\"ABC\""
            }

            flavor2 {
                applicationId "com.example.apps.myapp2"
                buildConfigField "int", "CONFIG_INT", "456"
                buildConfigField "String", "CONFIG_STRING", "\"QWE\""
            }
        }
```

And access to fields

```
BuildConfig.CONFIG_INT
BuildConfig.CONFIG_STRING
```

Don't forget to press **Synchronize** button (right from Save) to rebuild you BuildConfig with new fields. In the newest versions of gradle it's possible to declare **Android resources**  [Watch there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java).

Switch flavoirs from **Build Variants**

[image: Build Variants] in Android Studio

Comment: Thanks! So how do I switch to build from one flavor to another?

Comment: Little add for package name. Use **applicationId** for it.

Comment: And to switch flavor use **Build Variants** menu in Android Studio.