# How to get acces to values from another gradle file?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Ok, here is my current build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: '../config.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
       applicationId ""
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 21
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
        resValue "int", "amountOfTables", amountOfTables
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    howManyTables.execute()
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.4'
}
```

and that's the config.gradle:

```
def amountOfTables = 15

task howManyTables << {
    println amountOfTables
}
```

The question is:
Why can I get access to howManyTables task from config.gradle. But can't get access to defined variable? I want to create custom config.gradle with predefined values. And then use them as variables in my Android app. (like baseURL, type of data, etc...). And them, depending of that data build my logic. Anyway, the question is clear i hope ;) Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because You defined the variable with `def` - so it's *local* in the script itself. Try:

**config.gradle**

```
project.ext.amountOfTables = 15
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: 'config.gradle' //correct path should be here
println project.amountOfTables
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. It was actually easy)) But I can't accept answer yet=( Here's one more question, if you don't mind: it says now "Gradle DSL method not found: resValue()". But according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java it should work fine

Comment: Ye, I'll handle this myself. Thank you, anyway