# Using Build variable in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, build.gradle

How to include variable from build.gradle inside AndroidManifest data tag.

I tried

```
<data scheme="${applicationId}.something">
```

But I received the error **NullPointerException: No record for key [data]**

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954071/how-can-i-access-a-buildconfig-value-in-my-androidmanifest-xml-file

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
...
defaultConfig {
...

   buildConfigField("String", "PROVIDER_KEY", "\"$applicationId\"")
   manifestPlaceholders = [providerKey: "$applicationId"]

}
```

And using

```
<provider
        android:name=".provider.NavigationMenuContent"
        android:authorities="${providerKey}"
        android:exported="false" />
```

or

```
static final String AUTHORITY = BuildConfig.PROVIDER_KEY;
```

See docs
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables