# How to set Google Analytics tracker ID in build.gradle instead of xml?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, google-analytics-sdk

All environment specific keys like server URL and SDK keys are currently kept in the `build.gradle` file. The purpose of this is to easily switch between developing and production environments using `buildTypes`.

I added Google Analytics to the app, which is configured via a `res/xml/app_tracker.xml` file that contains the tracker ID:

`<string name="ga_trackingId" translatable="false">UA-12345678-9</string>`

How can the tracker ID be moved into the `build.gradle` file's `buildTypes` to define a different GA tracker ID for each environment?

---

### Edit

I tried this in `build.gradle`:

```
buildTypes {
  release {
    resValue "string", "GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKER_ID", "UA-12345678-9"
  }
}
```

Which auto-generates an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY -->

    <!-- Values from build type: debug -->
    <string name="GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKER_ID" translatable="false">UA-12345678-9</string>

</resources>
```

But this does not seem to work in the `app_tracker.xml` file:

```
<string name="ga_trackingId" translatable="false">@string/GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKER_ID</string>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access a BuildConfig value in my AndroidManifest.xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954071/how-can-i-access-a-buildconfig-value-in-my-androidmanifest-xml-file)

Comment: I tried the solution in your linked answer but it didn't work, that's why I posted this question, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

From question you asked, You to want to maintain multiple tracker ids for a different environment.

So instead of maintaining UA-XXX in build.gradle, we need to specify multiple xml files with different UA-XXX in Application class

```
private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXXX-Y";


  public enum TrackerName {
    PROD_ENV_TRACKER, // Tracker used for Production Environment.
    DEV_ENV_TRACKER, // Tracker used for Devlopment Environment.
    STAGE_ENV_TRACKER, // Tracker used for Stage Environment.
  }

  HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

  public AnalyticsSampleApp() {
    super();
  }
  synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

      GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
      Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.PROD_ENV_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
          : (trackerId == TrackerName.DEV_ENV_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.dev_env_tracker)
              : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.stage_env_tracker);
      mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
  }
}
```