# build gradle variables to be used in code depending on flavor AND build type

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Is there a way to use variables from build.gradle in my code, which is dependent on flavor AND buildType?

In this example here: [Is it possible to declare a variable in Gradle usable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java) the new resource value only depends on if its a debug or release build type.

What I would like to have is one variable for each possible buildVariant.

so something like:

```
flavor1Debug   => resValue "string", "app_name", "App 1 Debug"
flavor1Release => resValue "string", "app_name", "App 1"
flavor2Debug   => resValue "string", "app_name", "App 2 Debug"
flavor2Release => resValue "string", "app_name", "App 2"
```

Is there a nice way to do this either through build.gradle or another way that doesn't included switches or if else statements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In build.gradle for your app, one way you could achieve this would be:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        productFlavors.flavor1.buildConfigField "String", "app_name", "\"App 1 Debug\""
        productFlavors.flavor2.buildConfigField "String", "app_name", "\"App 2 Debug\""
    }
    release {
        productFlavors.flavor1.buildConfigField "String", "app_name", "\"App 1\""
        productFlavors.flavor2.buildConfigField "String", "app_name", "\"App 2\""
    }
}
```

Note that you'll want to define your productFlavors{} block before your buildTypes.

Comment: sorry I thought this worked first, but the app never get the value from debug, it always takes the release. No matter which build variant I select when I run the app.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include a more complete version of your build file? Also, which version of the gradle plugin are you using? I'm using 1.1.3

Comment: Why the `"String"` declaration?