# Error:(47, 0) Could not get unknown property 'IS_CI_BUILD' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After performing a `rm -rf ~/.gradle` and `rm -rf ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists` (needed in order to prevent my app from applying cached versions of some third-party library) I can no longer build my app, as the line

```
buildTypes.each {
    it.buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_CI_BUILD', IS_CI_BUILD
}
```

leads to this error:

```
Error:(47, 0) Could not get unknown property 'IS_CI_BUILD' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.
```

What could possibly be the reason? From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226978/could-not-find-property-xxxx-on-com-android-build-gradle-appextension-decorate) I infered that my IS_CI_BUILD property should be a boolean, but whenever I change it to `true` or `false` and I try to run app, an Edit Configuration dialog pops up in which I am not really sure what to do.

Comment: Are you tried to sync gradle?

Comment: I did multiple restarts, invalidate cache, Sync Project With Gradle Files, clean, rebuild. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, it turns out that now my problematic build.gradle line needs to look like this:

```
 buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'boolean', 'IS_CI_BUILD', 'Boolean.parseBoolean("true")'
    }
```

I just opened my generated BuildConfig class and noticed there are two ways gradle generates these static variables, either with literals like this:
`public static final boolean fabricEnabled = true;`
or like this: `public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");` (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889098/why-does-the-buildconfig-class-use-boolean-parseboolean-instead-of-literal-val)).

My IS_CI_BUILD wasn't even there, so I figured AS for some reason cannot generate it successfully into BuildConfig class and decided to give this second method a try. It worked!