# is BuildConfig.DEBUG a compile-time constant?

Tags: android, kotlin, compile-time-constant, android-r8

I'm trying to create a `ProductionRelease` compile-time constant, so that R8 can omit our debugging codes in the final production apk. I hit a roadblock whereby the `BuildConfig.DEBUG` is not assignable to a `const val`.

```
// MyApplication.kt

companion object {
        const val isDebug = BuildConfig.DEBUG
        const val isProductionRelease = BuildConfig.FLAVOR == "production" && !BuildConfig.DEBUG
}
```

[image: const val initializer should be a constant value]

Upon further checking, I found out `BuildConfig.DEBUG` is wrapped with a `Boolean.parseBoolean()` wrapper.

```
// BuildConfig.java

/**
 * Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY
 */

public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com...";
  ...
}
```

Questions here is:

1. Why can't I assign a static final boolean to a const val?
2. Why BuildConfig.DEBUG can't be generated using true|false directly but have to parse through a `parseBoolean` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why can't I assign a static final boolean to a const val?

`static final` variable is not initialized at compile time. So we cannot assign uninitialized value to `const val`.

> 2. Why BuildConfig.DEBUG can't be generated using true|false directly but have to parse through a parseBoolean function?

Boolean literals inside the `BuildConfig` class are going to produce IDE warnings when using them in your code (at least within Android Studio).
You can see more details in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29889098/6686126).

---

Instead of `DEBUG`, you can use `BUILD_TYPE`.

```kotlin
const val isDebug = BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE == "debug"
const val isProductionRelease = BuildConfig.FLAVOR == "production" && !isDebug
```

Or you can also add new constants as boolean literals in BuildConfig.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'DEBUG_CONST', 'true'
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField 'boolean', 'DEBUG_CONST', 'false'
    }
}
```