# Accessing properties from gradle.properties in java?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I have modified the `gradle.properties` file in the root of my android project with the following:

```
 myNewProp=1
```

And I would now like to access it via the JAVA code in my android project. But I can't seem to do it. I have tried BuildConfig, but the property isn't there.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Here's something similar ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java . Hope it's still relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

To add a value that can be accessed in the java code you use the following:

```
buildConfigField "int", "myNewProp", "1"
```

A `BuildConfig` class will then be created in your project that will contain all of you values.

Comment: so you know how I might iterate over all the properties and add them to the BuildConfig class?  Also do you know how I would then access that class in Java?