# Declare variables in gradle to use in Android project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, buildconfig

I am reading config fields from an `environment.properties` file that I would like to reuse in my Android application. I have tried various ways to get values from gradle's build without success (Gradle 2.7):

```
buildTypes {

    debug {

        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_SCHEME", getBuildConfigField('SERVER_SCHEME')
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_BASE_URL", getBuildConfigField('SERVER_BASE_URL')
        buildConfigField "int", "SERVER_PORT", getBuildConfigField('SERVER_PORT')
        buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_CONTEXT",  getBuildConfigField('SERVER_CONTEXT')

    }
}
```

where `getBuildConfigFields(key)` is a function defined in my `config.gradle`reading a file and returning the value corresponding to the specified key.
I have tried :

- `buildConfigField "TYPE" "KEY" "VALUE"`,
- `buildConfigField("TYPE" "KEY" "VALUE")`
- `resValue "TYPE" "KEY" "VALUE"`

But none of the are working with gradle errors like :

```
Error:(71, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'buildConfigField()' Possible causes:
The project 'app' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Gradle settings
The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin
```

I am using gradle 2.7 to build my android app and found these ways to set `BuildConfigFields` in different answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17201265/749021) but they seem to be outdated for newer versions. What functions can I use to get values from gradle in my application ?

Thank you !

Comment: the question linked is still valid.

Comment: Agreed. I just pasted the code from the "Plugin version greater than 0.7.x" section of the accepted answer into an Android project, and it worked just fine, with both version 1.2.3 and 1.3.0 of the `com.android.tools.build:gradle` plugin.

Comment: I use external gradle with 2.7 version as I need to deploy to a Jenkins server on which only gradle 2.7 is available. I think there is still a way to do the same with newer versions of gradle but I could not find how