# How to replace string.xml values from productFlavours of build.gradle

Tags: android, xml

In strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string>name="app_name">App_Name</string>
<string>name="app_port">https://example.com</string>
<string>name="app_key">App_Key</string>
</resources>
```

In build.gradle

```
productFlavors {
    production {
        applicationId = "com.example.production"
    }
    staging {
        applicationId = "com.example.staging"
        //code to manipulate strings.xml value because for production and staging app_name, app_port and key are different
    }
}
```

I need a code code to manipulate strings.xml from productFlavours of build.gradle file instead of creating separate folder for staging and production.

Comment: Do they have different values or are keys themselves different?

Comment: I think following link might help you
[enter link description here][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17201265/1182022

Comment: @mixel What ever i specified with in strings.xml file are different for staging.

Comment: @Archana Creating separate folder for product flavor is right solution. I do not understand why it's not suitable for you. Could you provide question with more details of your specific case?

Comment: @mixel I am trying to change strings.xml values without creating separate folders for staging and production.

Comment: @AdnanAmjad  On running staging it should select this port and app name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an answer. Using **resValue** as follows with in gradle

```
productFlavors {
production {
    applicationId = "com.example.production"
    resValue 'string', 'APP_NAME', 'app_name'
}
staging {
    applicationId = "com.example.staging"
    resValue 'string', 'APP_NAME', 'app_name_stage'
}
```

It will create generated.xml file with in build directory. 
To get the values in code, use generated resource like all others as follows,

```
getResources().getString(R.string.APP_NAME)
```