# set android:value with a gradle properties on manifest

Tags: android, facebook, gradle

I have my facebook application id on my gradle properties with :

```
FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

and I set in my defaultConfig :

```
manifestPlaceholders = [facebookAppId: FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID]
```

then, I want to use this in my manifest with :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="${facebookAppId}" />
```

but it doesn't work. The only things working are to set my faceboook id in a string :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

or to put this directly with :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="\ XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```

but I must set my facebook id in my gradle properties. What is the right way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Tried it as well and it didn't work for me. Even on android dev site they explicitly wrote value instead of getting value from a gradle variable: `manifestPlaceholders = [facebookAppId: "facebook-id-12345678"]`  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am new on Gradle, but if I understood your questions I would suggest using something like that:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        // ...
    }
    release {
        // ...
        resValue "string", "facebook_application_id", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
}
```

Then, at your release build, for this example, you can use it as

```
android:value="@string/facebook_application_id"
```

Or even

```
R.string.facebook_application_id
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks ! 
it may be useful so this link explain this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java

Comment: Nice it was what you were looking for. If you can mark the answer as the correct one, that helps me :-)

Comment: while it works, it is not secure. Strings can be easily extracted from an apk. See https://rammic.github.io/2015/07/28/hiding-secrets-in-android-apps/