# How to properly add property to build.gradle to access from java?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to add a property to `build.gradle` (so that I can access it from MyActivity.java).

As per [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java) this is what I have done:

```
// ...
buildTypes{ 
    debug {
            debuggable true
            buildConfigField "String"  , "pvs_debuggable", "truez"
          }
// ...
```

When I do this, a 'Sync Now' option appears, which I select.

But when I select it, `BuildConfig.java` is automatically opened, and with a warning: `Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited` *(other similar SO questions do not address my situation  as far as I can tell)*.

Also, two lines of code have been automatically added to `BuildConfig.java`:

```
  // Fields from build type: debug
  public static final String pvs_debuggable = truez;
```

Please notice how `truez` has no quotes around it even though it is a string *(I added the 'z' to ensure that AS wasn't trying to cast 'true' to true)*.

Also I should mention that the tab for this file has a red squiggly line beneath the name `BuildConfig.java` indicating a problem. And I am unable to run or debug the app.

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your `build.gradle` in this way:

```
buildTypes{
 debug { 
        debuggable true
        buildConfigField "String"  , "pvs_debuggable", "\"truez\""
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose that this gives me an insight to  gradle's build-phase parsing?? (eg the escaped quotes) ... thanks very much for the answer ... I had actually deleted the escaped quotes from my original copy/paste, thinking that they were an errant artifact of someone's code ... thanks