# Is there a way to make a variable compile time constant from an XML file?

Tags: java, android

I have strings stored in an XML file for my app (for easier changes and translations, etc). My question is if there is anyway to take a value from the table and set it in a compile time constant variable.

For example:

```
public static final String foo = /*grab string from resources*/
```

Right now I have this:

```
public static final String PROTO = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.stage_proto);
```

which when I later try to use it for a case label in a switch-case statement, I get an error saying it's not a constant expression.

Is there anyway to set a value from Resources to a compile time constant variable?

Comment: You would need to generate Java code from your XML with a string constant, and then refer to the generated code from your hand-written class.

Comment: Why is changing an XML file easier than changing a Java file? They are both just text files. If the value needs "translation", it is probably not a good candidate for a `switch` statement.

Comment: I dont think so, but if you are using gradle you might be do [>this<](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**It is not possible. Because in android xml files are compile time files so once apk is generated you can not change strings from xml files**

Comment: I don't want to change the string. I just want a reference to it that is compile time constant.