# Access a variable in Java or string.xml from Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-resources

I have a value for a String in String.xml

```
<string name="id">4</string>
```

and I have a class which contains a variable

```
public static int Id=1;
```

Now what I need is I want to get either of these two values in the gradle, which will check a condition and based on the condition it will rename my app. Below given is the part of the gradle code

```
def identifier //here i need to get value from the java or xml 
switch(identifier)
 {
  case 1: 
   temp="ApplicationNewName";break;
  }
 newName=newName.replace("-release",temp);
output.output.File=new File(output.outputFile.parent,newName);
```

My question is that, Can i access the variables initialised in the java file or string xml in gradle file ?

Answer (score 0):

You're approaching this problem backwards, Gradle gives you the ability to set those variables within the script itself and then you can further access those variables throughout your Android code. Here's a relevant answer for how you can set build configuration variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17201265/2168085

It also sounds like you are trying to build different apps from a single code base, or build variations of those apps. If that's the case then you should really look into `build flavors` to solve this problem. Essentially a build flavor allows you build different apps from a single main code base and apply variations or new functionality to the different flavors. This can be as basic as having a free and paid version of an app or a full white label code base where you can build very different apps from the same master code base. In Android these are more commonly known as `build variants` and the developer documentation gives plenty of good information on how to get started: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html