# Change Android application name and icon at build time

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

Is there any way to change Android application's configuration at build time? I would like to use the same code base for multiple apps and change only a few "parameters" such as:

- application icon
- package name/application id
- application name (displayable)
- backend endpoints
- Fabric/Analytics tokens/keys etc.

I know I can achieve this by using `buildVariants`/`productFlavors`, but I want to know if there is any way to to this from "command line" during/before build time without modifying application code or gradle files.

Comment: I can imagine you could use a `gradle.properties` file to inject runtime values via `BuildConfig`. Similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java but instead of hardcoded values, you use values added to the gradle.properties file. But this still means you need to do changes in code/gradle file