# Is it possible to declare a variable in gradle productFlavors and use it in Java?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I know that in `buildTypes` I can declare, but I want to declare in `productFlavors`.

**like this:**

```
productFlavors {
    f1 {
        some_variable: "v_f1"
    }
    f2 {
        some_variable: "v_f2"
    }
}
```

**similar question :**

[Is it possible to declare a variable in Gradle usable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, like this:

```
productFlavors {
    f1 {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "aBoolean", "true"    
        buildConfigField "String", "aString", "foo"
    }
    f2 {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "aBoolean", "false"    
        buildConfigField "String", "aString", "bar"
    }
}
```

then at runtime you can access them like:

```
if (BuildConfig.aBoolean) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sure** .

Access it via `BuildConfig.some_variable`.

You will get the variable value `according to the build variant` .