# Is there an easy way include common feature settings in gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Is there an easy way to include common flavor settings in a flavor when the flavors are split out by build settings?

Take the below example.  I'd like to have all the settings in the flavor1 group below included in both the Debug and Release flavors.  This is obviously a simplified example, as I have 4 flavors and over 20 settings common between them and I don't wan to duplicate them.

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        flavor1Debug {
            resValue 'string', 'application_name', 'DebugName'
        }
        flavor1Release {
            resValue 'string', 'application_name', 'RelaseName'
        }

        //flavor1 {
        //    buildConfigField 'String', 'DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_CODE', '"en"'
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, everything is described here [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java) :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `defaultConfig` section, you can provide the base configuration for all flavors in the `defaultConfig` block, and each flavor can change any of these default values. 
for example:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"www.example.com"]
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
      debug{...}
      release{...}
    }

   flavorDimensions "version"
   productFlavors {
     demo {
        dimension "version"
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"www.otherexample.com"]//this flavor change manifestPlaceholders 
        ...
     }
     full {
        dimension "version" //this flavor extends manifestPlaceholders from `defaultConfig`
        ...
     }
   }
```