# Android Studio is reading the - sign in my API key as an operation

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, api-key

In my app's gradle I defined my API_KEY as followed (changed it for the purpose of asking this question)

```
buildTypes.each {it.buildConfigField 'String', 'API_KEY', "AIuvSyTp2TG-P81edjKBRSGWoH8slLeurbg2HOc"}
```

But when I run the app, it's throwing me this error

```
com/projecttest/cloudvision/MainActivity.java   
error: cannot find symbol variable AIuvSyTp2TG  
error: cannot find symbol variable P81edjKBRSGWoH8slLeurbg2HOc
```

Apparently it's treating the - sign in my API key as some kind of operation? How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this work? `"\"AIuvSyTp2TG-P81edjKBRSGWoH8slLeurbg2HOc\""`

Comment: Yes it's resolved! May I know why would doing this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply surround the string with (escaped) quotes:

```
buildTypes.each {it.buildConfigField 'String', 'API_KEY', "\"AIuvSyTp2TG-P81edjKBRSGWoH8slLeurbg2HOc\""}
```

Why does this work? I have no idea. The syntax is pretty well documented in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java), but I have never been able to find the sort of official, detailed docs for `buildTypes` that Android provides for, say, their Java classes. (And the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin.groovy) doesn't make for a very easy read, either.)

**If you are reading this, and know where to find the docs, please leave a comment or suggest an edit!**

[Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.html) you can find a reference of examples using "buildConfigField", with "String" option.

[Here](https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-android-flavors-part-5-the-buildconfig-strikes-back-6230ef4e0d29) you can find information about breaking down the "buildConfigField" Parameters.

[Here](https://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-gradle-properties-to-build-gradle-to-buildconfig/), is another example configuring an API_ID.